# Trying to find any files that begin with a key name from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Trying to find any files that begin with a key name from a dictionary. Current code:

```
# Example of student dictionary
students = {'lastName-firstName': 'mum_email@optusnet.com.au', 'jones-bob': 'bob-jones@gmail.com', 'doe-john': 'dads_email@bigpond.net.au'}                

def files_to_attach():
    attachments = ['/Users/home/Downloads/Scale score ACER  copy.png']
    # Put file names from directory into a list
    # Example of files in list - f = ['lastName-firstName-pat-maths-plus-test-9-2017-03-22-10-23.png',
    #                                'lastName-firstName-pat-r-comprehension-test-9-2017-03-24-12-56.png',
    #                                'etc...']
    f = []
    for filenames in os.walk('/Users/home/Downloads/ACER-Results'):
        f.extend(filenames)
    # Find any files with student's name
    for key, value in students.iteritems():
        # UNSURE IF I NEED TO DO THIS???
        for files_to_attach in f:
            # If the start of the student file begins with the students key...
            if files_to_attach.startswith(key):
                # Add it to the attachments list.
                attachments.append(files_to_attach)
        # Sends email to parent with student's results attached
        send_mail(send_from, value, subject, text, attachments=[])
```

Getting this ERROR:

```
File "test.py", line 29, in files_to_attach
    if files_to_attach.startswith(key):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Do I need to use a regular expression (re) to search the files?

Comment: `for filenames in os.walk`: `filenames` is a tuple root/dirs/files. Check `os.walk` documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.walk` returns a tuple of `(root, dirs, files)` in a directory. In your code,

```
for filenanmes in os.walk(...):
    f.extend(filenames)
```

You are extending the list `f` with a tuple, so the final result of `f` will be a list of tuples. Later on, when you extract the contents of the list in

```
for files_to_attach in f:
    if files_to_attach.startswith(key):
        ...
```

here `files_to_attach` will be a tuple. What you should do is extract the contents of the tuple in the first for loop correctly:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(...):
    for fi in files:
        f.append(fi)
```

or another option:

```
for fi in os.listdir(...):
    if os.path.isfile(fi): # Get the correct path to fi
        f.append(fi)
```

Comment: Dear @Carles Mitjans, I have stopped getting the ERROR, thank you. But it doesn't seem to be appending the files to the 'attachments' variable. Do you know what might be doing wrong there?

Comment: @Phil this means the `if` statement before the attachment returns False. Try debugging with some `print` statements before the `if` statement to see what files_to_attach contains.

Comment: when I run a `print files_to_attach` under the `for files_to_attach in f:` it is printing the file names one letter at time instead the of the whole file name?

Comment: @Phil Because you are `extend`ing your `f` list. This will add each character at a time. Use `append` instead in the first loop (I edited my answer too)

Comment: I still have a lot of debugging to do!! Thank you for all of your help, greatly appreciated.